# Outlook for windows/mac showing tags in email

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, outlook

I am sending an email to verify user. Email are working fine when opened in browser website, when checked in browser it looks fine. For example when email is send to gmail or any other email site, it does not shows tags but when I open it in outlook 2013, it shows html tags.I don't want outlook to show tag[image]please help

```
$config = Array(
                 'protocol' => 'smtp',
                 'smtp_host' => 'smtp.brianvest.com.',
                 'smtp_port' => 465,
                 'smtp_user' => 'admin@brianvest.com', // change it to yours
                 'smtp_pass' => 'voting2016', // change it to yours
                 'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
                 'mailtype' => 'html',
              );


  $this->load->library('email', $config);
  $this->email->set_header('MIME-Version', '1.0; charset=utf-8'); 
  $this->email->set_header('Content-type', 'text/html');
  $this->email->from('info@senduleads.com', "Julie Italiano - Modern Office Methods");
  $this->email->to($email);  
  //$this->email->message("Dear Voter,\nPlease click on the URL below, or copy and paste it into your browser to verify your Email Address and Start Voting.\n\n http://www.example.com/JumpStartBeta/".$verificationText."\n"."\n\nThanks,\nJulie Italiano\nModern Office Methods");
$link = "http://example.com/Admin/change_password/$verificationText";
$title = 'Password Change Request for Jump Start Voting';
$this->email->message("Dear Voter,<br>Please click <a href='".$link."'>here</a> to verify your password.<br><br><br>Thanks,<br>Julie Italiano\nModern Office Methods");


  $this->email->subject($title);
  $this->email->send();
```

Comment: You need to specify that the email you're sending from your code has the body set as HTML: https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

Comment: I have the same setting but still not working specifically in outlook. While mail works fine in normal browser.

Comment: try to remove the set_header methods and the charset thing in your config